# Reading in JSON values not being evaluation right

Tags: python, json

I have a program running that reads in a JSON file. This JSON file has a couple of things: *captions* and "*boxes*". The captions are captions of images, and the boxes are little frames that cover parts of an image that you fed to the parent program (the produced this json file). It's not exactly important what these boxes do, really - all that needs to be known is that for every caption in the "captions" field, there is a box in the "boxes" field. A box is a list of four numbers: x, y, width, height. It forms a rectangle.

Anyway, I am doing something very simple - I made a simple program that would read in this JSON file and, through some different options, it would ask a user to provide for it a "box". If any of the JSON file boxes collide, intersect, overlay - whatever - with this box, it would produce the caption for said box. Helps with organization.

All good so far, I hope. I have two classes: Point and Box. "Point" is justa point in space, and "Box" is a box, or a rectangle. Take a look below:

```
import json

class Point:

"""A point identified by (x,y) coordinates."""

def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def as_tuple(self):
    """(x, y)"""
    return (self.x, self.y)
```

And BoxClass:

```
class Box:

"""A box identified by two points.

The box stores left, top, right, and bottom values.

Coordinates are based on screen coordinates.

origin                               top
+-----> x increases                |
|                           left  -+-  right
v                                  |
y increases                         bottom

set_points  -- reset box coordinates
contains  -- is a point inside?
overlaps  -- does a box overlap?
top_left  -- get top-left corner
bottom_right  -- get bottom-right corner
expanded_by  -- grow (or shrink)
"""

def __init__(self, pt1, pt2):
    """Initialize a box from two points."""
    self.set_points(pt1, pt2)

def set_points(self, pt1, pt2):
    """Reset the box coordinates."""
    (x1, y1) = pt1.as_tuple()
    (x2, y2) = pt2.as_tuple()
    self.left = min(x1, x2)
    self.top = min(y1, y2)
    self.right = max(x1, x2)
    self.bottom = max(y1, y2)               
    self.lt = Point(self.left, self.top)        #left-top point
    self.rb = Point(self.right, self.bottom)    #right-bottom point
    self.rt = Point(self.right, self.top)       #right-top point
    self.lb = Point(self.left, self.bottom)     #left-bottom point

def overlaps(self, other):
    """Return true if a box overlaps with this box."""
    if(self.lt.x > other.rb.x or other.lt.x > self.rb.x):
        return False

    if(self.rb.y < other.lt.y or other.rb.y < self.lt.y):
        return False

    return True

def __str__( self ):
    return "<Box (%s,%s)-(%s,%s)>" % (self.left,self.top,
        self.right,self.bottom)
```

Now, here is the confusing part. I am just testing this, and here is some code:

```
""" Opens and loads the JSON file."""
with open("results.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

captions = data["captions"]
boxes = data["boxes"]

lt = Point([0, 5000])
rt = Point([5000, 0])

rw = Box(lt, rt)

rx = Box(Point([130.05253601074, 375.44775390625]), Point([130.05253601074+119.79272460938, 375.44775390625+26.875732421875]))

print rw.overlaps(rx)
```

This prints "True" to the console. *As expected*.

Now, when I print this:

```
caption_counter = 0
for c, b in zip(captions, boxes):
    # This wraps around each individual caption, and each of the boxes for each caption (four elements inside the tuple)
    x, y, x2, y2 = b[0], b[1], b[0] + b[2], b[1] + b[3]
    lt = Point(x, y)
    rb = Point(x2, y2)
    dc_box = Box(lt, rb)
    caption_counter +=1
    if rw.overlaps(dc_box) or dc_box.overlaps(rw):
        print c
        counter += 1
        print caption_counter
```

Nothing prints! Nothing at all! I defined x,y,x2,y2 in that really weird way because I wanted to just ascertain everything being inputted into dc_box was 100% what I wanted to go through. And, I want you to take a look at this `else` statement I included (after nothing printed):

```
else:
    print b
    print dc_box.__str__
    print "\n"
```

That outputs MANY things, but the last item (basically, the last box) is this:

```
[130.05253601074, 375.44775390625, 119.79272460938, 26.875732421875]
<bound method Rect.__str__ of Rect(Point(130, 375), Point(249, 402))>
```

Does that seem familiar? Look at the first test I had! It's the same exact parameters for box "rx". And it overlaps with box "rw". Why is box "rw" NOT overlapping with dc_boc? Here is the [json file](https://ufile.io/yh6wm).

Comment: Can you build a [mcve] with only the smallest runnable code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Absolutely. One moment

Comment: Your `overlaps` is wrong. That or `Box.__init__`, depending on whether larger `y` values are supposed to go downwards or upwards.

Comment: [Example.](https://ideone.com/d6gZ6O)

Comment: Also, those are clearly not the same parameters.

Comment: @user2357112 How are those different parameters? Also, keep in mind that a "Box" is isa bounding rectangle, meanign you must provide to it the left-top point and the bottom-right point, not any arbitrary points.

Comment: `130.05253601074+119.79272460938` isn't `119.79272460938`. `0, 5000` isn't `130, 375`. Also, yes, I know what a Box is.

Comment: You set the top of the box to the *smaller* input y coordinate, but then when you check for overlaps, if one box's top coordinate is *smaller* than the other's bottom coordinate, you report no overlap. Think about that for a bit.

Comment: Alright, sorry, not sure I entirely understand your point. The four parameters I am getting from the json "box" are x, y, width, and height. the "last" dc_box is supposed to be exactly the same as box rx. rw box overlaps with rx, but rw does not overlap with dc_box, even though dc_box and rx are supposed  bto be exactly the same. if they are not ,can you explain how they are not ,because I do not see it

Comment: @user2357112 Okay... I fixed my overlaps function, I'm still very intereste in why you think rx and dc_box are not the same..

Comment: I'm interested in why you think they *are* they same. Your `print` shows that `dc_box` is `Rect(Point(130, 375), Point(249, 402))`. Does that look anything like what you set `rx` to?

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, I give up, what's wrong with my logic here? I see how different rx is - I don't even know how or why it worked to be honest - but why is it not overlapping? Because a box from 130, 275 to 249, 402 should be overlapping with a box that is from 0,5000 to 5000, 0, right?

Comment: Looking at this again... oh. You were passing a list to `Point` in the test that seemed to work, but `Point` isn't designed to take a list.

Comment: `rx` actually does look kind of like `dc_box` - there's the list problem, and there seems to be a cast to int going on somewhere in the dc_box example, but other than that, they seem to match. I misread the `b` handling earlier, which made them look more mismatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112). I was passing a list to `Point` when it is supposed to take two points, and I just never realized it. Also there was an error in my `overlaps` function.